# Using Eclipse AspectJ to Inject a Logger which Logs context/meta data of the code execute?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am trying to define an aspect to inject a logger.

I am looking to create something like:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public aspect LogInjector {

    private pointcut executionJoinPoints(): !within(LogInjector) && execution (* *.*(..));

    before(): executionJoinPoints(){
        // Get class name of the executed code
        clazz = ...
        final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(clazz);

        // Get method name of the executed code
        method = ...

        // Get params name, type and values triplet or values at least if the previous is not possible, of the executed code
        params = ...

        // Get call stack of the executed code
        stack = ...

        logger.trace("{}.{}({}) - {}", clazz.name(), method.name(), params, stack);
    }

    after(): executionJoinPoints(){
        // Get class name of the executed code
        clazz = ...
        final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(clazz);

        // Get method name of the executed code
        method = ...

        // Get return value or exception of the executed code
        result = ...

        logger.trace("{}.{} = {}", clazz.name(), method.name(), result);
    }
}
```

For this I want to retrieve execution metadata/context data:

- exceptions
- return values

How can get this metadata/context data?

Comment: So you are asking 6 different questions (number of bullet points), expecting someone to do the whole job for you. I see. May I ask if you read any documentation, tried any methods offered via auto-complete on your joinpoint or similar? Furthermore, are you aware of the fact that this kind of catch-all aspect will considerably slow down your application, targeting all method executions and extracting all possible detail information everywhere? Did you think about indentation in order to depict call hierarchies instead of creating stack traces for each called method?

Comment: For call, stack indentation will do.  This I can manage. Since asking the question I have figured out many of the items except how to log the return values and exceptions. Also, how do I make the aspect faster without slowing down my application? Basically I want to trace through the application logging the function calls, return values and exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep your aspect efficient, I recommend the following:

- Limit your pointcut to the target packages and classes you really wish to debug. Don't log/trace the whole world. You could also use an abstract base aspect with an abstract pointcut and extend the aspect into a concrete sub-aspect with a concrete pointcut. The latter can even be provided via XML configuration if you use load time weaving.
- Use an `around()` advice instead of a `before()` / `after()` pair. Then you only need to calculate some of the logged values once and use them both before and after the original method call done via `proceed()`.
- Simply log `thisJoinPoint` instead of piecing together bits contained therein by default. This will already give you the type of joinpoint, method signature including parameter types and return value.
- Don't log parameter names, the information adds no real value. Furthermore, parameter names are subject to refactoring and are only present if your code is compiled with debug information. Keep it simple and only log the parameter values.
- In the `around()` advice mentioned above you can enclose the `proceed()` call into `try-catch-finally` and conveniently handle and log any exceptions and stack traces and/or wrap checked exceptions into AspectJ's `SoftException` or a simple `RuntimeException` and re-throw them. Whatever is applicable to your situation.
- Method call results are just the results of `proceed()`, which would you also be what you need to return from the `around()` advice. You can also return something else instead (but it must have the correct return type) or completely skip `proceed()` if for whatever reason you wish to skip target method execution.

All of what I just said is written in the AspectJ manual or in any other AspectJ tutorial. You might want to read some of those next time before asking a general question like this one.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid `proceed()` and `try-catch`, but achieve the same. `try-catch` you have to rethrow so this will result in a modified stack trace. Also `proceed()` does more than just capturing the return value with minimal overhead.

Comment: Why are you concerned with premature optimisation if by design you create a slow aspect only used for debugging anyway? No-one in their right mind would always log every method call in a production environment. Why should `proceed()` have overhead? It just calls the target method, which needs to be done anyway. You could use `after returning` and `after throwing` advice instead, but then you have to calculate things to log multiple times. For your purpose and `around()` advice is simply the most efficient thing to do. If you think you know better, be my guest and go ahead.