# Handling void methods in assignment from proceed() in AOP using AspectJ

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am writing a very generic code to capture the return type using `around` as `result = proceed();` followed by `return result;`.

Some methods are of type `void`. E.g.

```java
void doPrint() { 
   System.out.println("Doing something"); 
}
```

How can these methods of return type `void` be handled in a generic way along with methods returning a value or throwing an exception?

The code I have so far is:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import org.aspectj.lang.SoftException;
import org.aspectj.lang.Signature;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.CodeSignature;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.SourceLocation;

public aspect LogInjector {
    private pointcut executionJoinPoints(): !within(LogInjector) && execution (* *.*(..));

    Object around(): executionJoinPoints(){
        SourceLocation loc;
        CodeSignature sig;
        
        Class<?> type;
        
        Logger logger;
        
        Object result;
        try {
            loc = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSourceLocation();
            sig = (CodeSignature) thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
            
            type = loc.getWithinType();
            if (type == null) type = sig.getDeclaringType();
            
            logger = LogManager.getLogger(type);
            
            result = proceed();
            return result;
        } catch (RuntimeException rte) {
            result = rte;
            throw rte;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            result = t;
            throw new SoftException(t);
        } finally {
            logger.trace("Source location: {} | Join Point: {} | Signature: {} | Args: {} | Result: {}", loc, thisJoinPointStaticPart, sig, Arrays.deepToString(thisJoinPoint.getArgs()), result);
        }
    }

}
```

Corrections adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64084260/4) by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1082681/).

Comment: P.S.: Even a cursory glance at your code tells me that it will never even compile like this. So you have much more basic issues than handling void methods. Besides, you did not mention what your problem with void methods actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version of this question I commented on you had forgotten `return result;` after `result = proceed();` which later you have corrected. That was a good first step. But still your code would not compile because:

- The `around()` advice does not declare a return type.
- You cannot throw a `Throwable` from an `around()` advice, only a `RuntimeException`. Hence, you need to wrap each checked `Exception`, `Error` or `Throwable` in something like AspectJ's `SoftException` or simply in a `RuntimeException`.

So please when posting non-compilable code, please mention that fact and also post the compiler errors you get. Do not pretend the code works and there is just a detail problem about `void` method handling.

Further problems are:

- You print the signature which is redundant because you also print the joinpoint already containing the same signature.
- You determine the declaring type but never print it.
- You import `org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.ast.Proceed`, making the aspect dependent on a non-AspectJ class. More precisely, the class if from AJDT (AspectJ Development Tools), an Eclipse plugin for AspectJ.

I am also not so sure it is a good idea to overwrite the result by a caught exception and print it as such, but in my following [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which was your job to provide and again you didn't do it just like for the previous question) I left it unchanged.

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application = new Application();
    application.doSomething("foo");
    try {
      application.doSomethingSpecial("bar");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    application.doSomethingElse("zot");
  }

  public int doSomething(String string) {
    System.out.println("Doing something: " + string);
    return 42;
  }

  public void doSomethingSpecial(String string) throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("checked exception");
  }

  public void doSomethingElse(String string) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("runtime exception");
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

Please note that I removed Log4J and just print to the console in order to boil down the code to the important part. You can easily add the library again. I did not want to manually add it to my sample program and then try if it was Log4J 1.x or 2.x.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import static java.util.Arrays.deepToString;

import org.aspectj.lang.SoftException;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.CodeSignature;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.SourceLocation;

public aspect LogInjector {
  private pointcut executionJoinPoints() :
    !within(LogInjector) && execution (* *(..));

  Object around() : executionJoinPoints() {
    SourceLocation sourceLocation = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSourceLocation();
    CodeSignature signature = (CodeSignature) thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
    Class<?> type = sourceLocation.getWithinType();
    if (type == null)
      type = signature.getDeclaringType();
    Object result = null;
    try {
      result = proceed();
      return result;
    } catch (RuntimeException rte) {
      result = rte;
      throw rte;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      result = t;
      throw new SoftException(t);
    } finally {
      System.out.printf(
        "Source location: %s | Type: %s | Join Point: %s | Args: %s | Result: %s%n",
        sourceLocation, type, thisJoinPoint, deepToString(thisJoinPoint.getArgs()), result
      );
    }
  }

}
```

As you can see, the aspect simply re-throws runtime exceptions (no need to wrap them into another runtime exception) and wraps other throwables. This is also necessary because otherwise exceptions thrown through a hierarchy of calls would be wrapped multiple times like Russian Matryoshka dolls, which is something we want to avoid.

**Console log:**

```
Doing something: foo
Source location: Application.java:15 | Type: class de.scrum_master.app.Application | Join Point: execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething(String)) | Args: [foo] | Result: 42
Source location: Application.java:20 | Type: class de.scrum_master.app.Application | Join Point: execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingSpecial(String)) | Args: [bar] | Result: java.lang.Exception: checked exception
org.aspectj.lang.SoftException
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingSpecial_aroundBody5$advice(Application.java:28)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingSpecial(Application.java:1)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main_aroundBody0(Application.java:8)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main_aroundBody1$advice(Application.java:21)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:1)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: checked exception
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingSpecial_aroundBody4(Application.java:21)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingSpecial_aroundBody5$advice(Application.java:21)
    ... 4 more
Source location: Application.java:24 | Type: class de.scrum_master.app.Application | Join Point: execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingElse(String)) | Args: [zot] | Result: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: runtime exception
Source location: Application.java:4 | Type: class de.scrum_master.app.Application | Join Point: execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[])) | Args: [[--command, --option=123]] | Result: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: runtime exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: runtime exception
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingElse_aroundBody6(Application.java:25)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingElse_aroundBody7$advice(Application.java:21)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingElse(Application.java:1)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main_aroundBody0(Application.java:12)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main_aroundBody1$advice(Application.java:21)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:1)
```

The log shows that both void and non-void methods are handles nicely and that even the contents of the `main()` arguments array - I started the sample application with command line parameters `--command --option=123` - are nicely printed because I am using `Arrays.deepToString(thisJoinPoint.getArgs())` instead of `Arrays.toString(thisJoinPoint.getArgs())`.

---

So, like I said: I don't understand why you think you have problems with `void` methods while in reality you have a whole bunch of other problems. Did you ever read an AspectJ manual or tutorial and using sample code to start with or are you just using the "trial & error" method?

P.S.: I would never use the source location in an aspect because an aspect is not a debugger and source code is prone to refactoring anyway. If the code is compiled without debug info, you do not have the source location information in the byte code anyway, so you cannot rely on it. An aspect or logging in general are not replacements for a debugger.

---

**Update:** In comparison to your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63988698/1082681) now you don't log both before and after the target method call but only afterwards. In this case a combination of `after() returning` and `after() throwing` advice would both be more efficient and simpler to implement because you could avoid exception handling, re-throwing, and the `finally` block. When in the other question I recommended an `around()` advice I did so because I saw that your original `before()` and `after()` advice each had to determine the same information in order to log it, i.e. twice per method. But if you only need it once, `around()` is actually unnecessary.

---

**Update 2:** You asked:

> I am running into another problem. By throwing `SoftException` and `RuntimeException` the `catch` blocks are not catching the exceptions supposed to be thrown and caught as per the method signatures in libraries as per normal behaviour.

If you want the exceptions unchanged, use a combination of `after() returning` (printing the result) and `after() throwing` (unchanged exceptions, no need to wrap them) as mentioned above. See the [AspectJ manual](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-advice.html) for more information.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import static java.util.Arrays.deepToString;

import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.CodeSignature;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.SourceLocation;

public aspect LogInjector {
  private pointcut executionJoinPoints() :
    !within(LogInjector) && execution (* *(..));

  after() returning (Object result): executionJoinPoints() {
    SourceLocation sourceLocation = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSourceLocation();
    CodeSignature signature = (CodeSignature) thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
    Class<?> type = sourceLocation.getWithinType();
    if (type == null)
      type = signature.getDeclaringType();
    System.out.printf("Source location: %s | Type: %s | Join Point: %s | Args: %s | Result: %s%n",
      sourceLocation, type, thisJoinPoint, deepToString(thisJoinPoint.getArgs()), result
    );
  }

  after() throwing (Throwable error): executionJoinPoints() {
    SourceLocation sourceLocation = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSourceLocation();
    CodeSignature signature = (CodeSignature) thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
    Class<?> type = sourceLocation.getWithinType();
    if (type == null)
      type = signature.getDeclaringType();
    System.out.printf("Source location: %s | Type: %s | Join Point: %s | Args: %s | Error: %s%n",
      sourceLocation, type, thisJoinPoint, deepToString(thisJoinPoint.getArgs()), error
    );
  }

}
```

The console log will change to:

```
Doing something: foo
Source location: Application.java:15 | Type: class de.scrum_master.app.Application | Join Point: execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething(String)) | Args: [foo] | Result: 42
Source location: Application.java:20 | Type: class de.scrum_master.app.Application | Join Point: execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingSpecial(String)) | Args: [bar] | Error: java.lang.Exception: checked exception
java.lang.Exception: checked exception
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingSpecial(Application.java:21)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:8)
Source location: Application.java:24 | Type: class de.scrum_master.app.Application | Join Point: execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingElse(String)) | Args: [zot] | Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: runtime exception
Source location: Application.java:4 | Type: class de.scrum_master.app.Application | Join Point: execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[])) | Args: [[--command, --option=123]] | Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: runtime exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: runtime exception
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingElse(Application.java:25)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:12)
```

Comment: Please note my update at the end of the answer concerning the difference between this question and your original one.

Comment: I am running into another problem. By throwing `SoftException` and `RuntimeException` the cache blocks are not catching the `Exceptions` supposed to be thrown and caught as per the method signatures in libraries as per normal behaviour. Also, should I as this as another follow up question?