# How do you create an aspect with per class, per object and per method/source-location parts in AOP using AspectJ

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I want to create an aspect instance per class, per object and per method/source-location parts.

More particularly:

- Some values only change from class to class, but needs to be computed only once per class, hence they need to be deduced once per class. E.g. storing the `Class` would be per class, also a reference to the `Logger` for a particular class for logging.
- Some values change from method to method, but needs to be computed only once per method, hence they need to be deduced once per method. E.g. the method signature would be per method per class. This data does not change due to object instance or invocation.
- Some values change from instance/object to instance/object, but needs to be computed only once per instance/object, hence they need to be deduced once per instance/object. E.g. object ID, which would be instance dependent.
- Some values change from object to object, but needs to be computed only once per object per field or method, hence they need to be deduced once per object per field or method. E.g. invocation count of a method, which would be method and object dependent.
- Some values change from call to call, hence they need to be deduced/computed for every call. E.g. getting method parameters in AspectJ. This is dependent on the method, object and call.

I am trying to create aspects which store these deduced/computed values. In order not to incur more than whats is needed in terms of memory and computing. How can this be implemented in Eclipse AspectJ AOP?

What I have being trying to do so far was to create a hierarchy like this:

```
aspect Base {
    // Singleton - data items for the whole program computed and stored once
    // This is shared across all the objects in the application regardless of the class

    protected pointcut executionJoinPoints(): !within(Base+) && execution (* *.*(..));
}

aspect PerClass extends Base perthis(executionJoinPoints()) {
    // Per class - store class-specific data computed and stored once per class
    // Since this is class-specific, need to know what class this corresponds to
    // This is shared across all the objects of the same class
}

aspect PerMethodPerClass extends PerClass percflow(executionJoinPoints()) {
    // Per method - store method specific data computed and stored once per method as fields
    // Since this is method-specific, need to know what method this corresponds to
    // This is shared across all the objects of the same class
}

aspect PerObject extends PerMethodPerClass perthis(executionJoinPoints()) {
    // Per object/instance - store object/instance-specific data computed and stored once per object
    // Since this is object/instance-specific, need to know what object/instance this corresponds to
    // This is specific to the object/instance
}

aspect PerMethodPerObject extends PerObject percflow(executionJoinPoints()) {
    // Per method per object - store method specific data computed and stored once per method as fields for every object instance
    // Since this is method-specific, need to know what method this corresponds to and also what object this corresponds to
    // This is specific to the object/instance and particular method
}


public aspect PerCall extends PerMethodPerInstance {
    // Per call - handle data which change from call to call
    // This is specific to the call or invocation or execution
}
```

I am trying to implement:

- logging and tracing
- metrics and statistics collection for the program execution

using AspecJ AOP. For the statistics, I collect I need an aspect instance per class, per object and per method/source-location parts to store and collect the relevant data.

E.g. a method related statistics will be computed and stored in a `PerMethod` aspect. Also, it will be easier to lookup method-specific counters are accessible instance than looking it up in a large data structure. What is required here is that the aspect is instantiated once for each method. Similarly for classes, objects, etc.

Collecting execution statistics will incur some overhead but in doing so I am trying to keep it minimal hence why I want to have specific aspects of each case.

I am asking this to learn how to do this in AspectJ than trying to solve a specific problem. Once I try implementing it specific problems might pop up which I can share more specific examples of that I tried and the errors or problems it created.

Comment: The question is unclear. So is your code which again does not compile. Please use [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64084260/1082681) as a starting point and also the sample application class there or a variant of it, then please describe what you expect to be printed. Your code with `...` does not speak for itself. Why would you intercept the same joinpoint multiple times? What do you mean by _"per class, per object and per method/source-location parts_? Why are you still obsessed with source locations anyway? Like I said before, AOP is not meant to replace a debugger.

Comment: I added more explanation to make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to write this as an answer, but it is too long for a comment.

The problem with this question is that, despite the extensive explanation, you only explain **how** you wish to do something technically, without even once saying **what** the problem is you are trying to solve. This makes the question a wonderful example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898).

- What does your aspect do?
- Are you running into memory or performance problems?
- Are you sure that not your broad catch-all pointcut in combination with the advice code as such - in previous questions you wanted to log everything about each method execution in meticulous detail, emulating some kind of debugger - is the problem?
- Are you having a problem at all? If so, you did not state it. You might just be doing premature optimisation.

You are trying to save memory and CPU cycles, I got that from your question.

- Are you aware of the fact that by trying to do so you are creating many many aspect instances via `per...` clauses instead of using the default AspectJ singleton aspect instantiation model?
- Did you measure if that makes things better and not maybe even worse?

Actually your question does not present a real problem, you are showing a hierarchy of aspects doing absolutely nothing. So the question format as such is not compatible with StackOverflow. This is a Q/A platform, not a discussion forum. Me answering by actually asking a lot instead of presenting a solution for your problem is already a symptom of it. Opinionated debates is exactly what SO is not for. So like I said before in the other questions: The best way to ask questions is to present an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a clear problem description, code others can run and reproduce your problem.

---

**Update:** As you can see in the AspectJ manual, there are the following [aspect instantiation types](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-aspects.html#aspect-instantiation):

- singleton
- per object (`perthis()` vs. `pertarget()` which is e.g. different for `call()` pointcuts but should be the same for `execution()`)
- per control flow (`percflow()` vs `percflowbelow()`)
- per type (`pertypewithin()`, described [here](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/pertypewithin.html))

Please note that "per control flow" is not the same as "per method". As documented, an aspect instance will be created each time a certain control flow is entered, e.g. each time a method is executed. If the same method is executed 12,345 times, then 12.345 aspect instances will be created. So if you wish to gather per-method statistics, you better store the information in the corresponding class's per-type aspect instance. For your "per call" requirement, I think a "per control flow" advice would be appropriate.

Now we are done here. Like I said, if you wish to discuss your application design ideas here, it is the wrong place. So I will stop responding here and wait for you to present concrete new questions with MCVE which can be answered clearly and correctly instead of sparking discussions. I helped as much as I could now, more than I should have because the question actually should be closed as off-topic IMO.

Good luck with your interesting project. If you need more consulting, I am also doing this as a day time job and you can hire me, of course. ;-)

Otherwise I want to encourage you to create verifiable facts by just implementing something instead of asking a whole bunch of theoretical questions here (3 of which I have answered by now) and just see if your ideas work. You seem to like to theorise. Thinking is good, but so is doing. Use both and you will make more progress and iteratively (in-)validate your ideas.

Comment: Added further clarification.